# Run a script.sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

When trying to run a @'c:/.../.sql' on sqldeveloper an error occures : impossible to find the path ??

Comment: you may try to remove quotes around the path

Comment: didn't use them .

Comment: on a windows system try to use backslashes "\" , instead of slashes "/".

Comment: it didn't work. Is it related to having permission to execute the script ?

Comment: are you sure is your script at that path? or is this script read-only?

Comment: yes i'm sure it is the correct path but the script is read only

Comment: ok, remove check next to read-only check-box to make the file executable.

Comment: Once i run my sql developer as admin it worked

Answer (score 0):

This, literally

```
@c:\temp\test.sql
```

executed in SQL Developer's Worksheet works just fine. (Software version is 17.4, if that matters).